# Capitalizing each word in \glsentrylong

Tags: glossaries

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\let\oldmakefirstuc\makefirstuc
\renewcommand*{\makefirstuc}[1]{%
  \def\gls@add@space{}%
  \mfu@capitalisewords#1 \@nil\mfu@endcap
}
\def\mfu@capitalisewords#1 #2\mfu@endcap{%
  \def\mfu@cap@first{#1}%
  \def\mfu@cap@second{#2}%
  \gls@add@space
  \oldmakefirstuc{#1}%
  \def\gls@add@space{ }%
  \ifx\mfu@cap@second\@nnil
    \let\next@mfu@cap\mfu@noop
  \else
    \let\next@mfu@cap\mfu@capitalisewords
  \fi
  \next@mfu@cap#2\mfu@endcap
}
\makeatother
```

The following capitalize the first letter of each word. however, it displays the abbr. I need to modify it to `\glsentrylong`.

```
\newacronym{tla}{TLA}{three lettered acronym}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsfirst{tla}

\Glsfirst{tla}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) v4.22 onward you can use `\glsentrytitlecase{tla}{long}`. Alternatively ([`mfirstuc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc) v1.10 onward) you can use `\ecapitalisewords{\glsentrylong{tla}}`, which fully expands its argument before applying `\capitalisewords`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym{tla}{TLA}{three lettered acronym}

\begin{document}

glossaries v4.22 onward: \glsentrytitlecase{tla}{long}.

mfirstuc v1.10 onward: \ecapitalisewords{\glsentrylong{tla}}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! How would that work if I want to capitalize the plural? What would you recommend to use for chapter names / PDF bookmarks?

Comment: @bonanza For the plural, replace `\glsentrylong` with `\glsentrylongpl` or replace `\glsentrytitlecase{tla}{long}` with `\glsentrytitlecase{tla}{longpl}`. Unfortunately `\capitalisewords` isn't fully expandable as so can't be used in PDF bookmarks. (In fact, the same is true for the underlying `\uppercase` macro.)